# How do I specify a port in a Chocolatey package install script?

Tags: shell, powershell, port, chocolatey

I created a PowerShell script which asks the user whether they want to install Chocolatey and then installs a bunch of applications and moves some files.

I'm using this on the corporate network and sadly, the proxy settings that we use are posing a problem. When I execute the Chocolatey script, it says there's an error and it can't download the package. The most annoying thing is the error description is "No more data available". So whilst trying to run the script, I ran Wireshark in the background and was told that the script is trying to connect directly to a box, where it shouldn't be and that's why it's being rejected.

I was told to fix this, I need to force the script to go out of port 80. Which I'm not aware of how to do, so was looking for some advice on how to achieve this.

I would like to think it was just as simple as adding `:80` somewhere but, i've tried that and no luck.

```
#-Setting HTTP/S Proxy's-#

write-host "Configuring local proxy settings"
cscript configs\SetProxy_underscore.vbs

function Install-NeededFor {
param(
   [string] $packageName = ''
  ,[bool] $defaultAnswer = $true
)

  if ($packageName -eq '') { return $false }

  $yes = '6'
  $no = '7'
  $msgBoxTimeout='-1'
  $defaultAnswerDisplay = 'Yes'
  $buttonType = 0x4;
  if (!$defaultAnswer) { $defaultAnswerDisplay = 'No'; $buttonType= 0x104; }

  $answer = $msgBoxTimeout
  try {
    $timeout = 10
    $question = "Do you need to install $($packageName)? Defaults to `'$defaultAnswerDisplay`' after $timeout seconds"
    $msgBox = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $answer = $msgBox.Popup($question, $timeout, "Install $packageName", $buttonType)
  } catch {
  }

  if ($answer -eq $yes -or ($answer -eq $msgBoxTimeout -and $defaultAnswer -eq $true)) {
    write-host "Installing $packageName"
    return $true
  }

  write-host "Not installing $packageName"
  return $false
}

#-install chocolatey-#

if (Install-NeededFor 'chocolatey') {
  iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
}

choco install dotnet4.5 -y
cinst nuget.commandline -y
cinst chefdk -y
cinst notepadplusplus -y
cinst vagrant -y
cinst vagrant-winrm-config -y
cinst virtualbox -version 4.3.12 -y
choco install virtualbox -version 4.3.12 -y
cinst atom -y
cinst putty -y
cinst winscp -y
cinst conemu -y
cinst launchy -y
cinst everything -y
choco install git.install -y -params '"/GitAndUnixToolsOnPath"'
choco install git-credential-winstore -y

vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus
```

Comment: PowerPoint <> PowerShell.  Did you perhaps make a mistake in tagging this?

Comment: I did indeed. Thanks for spotting it. Edited it.

Comment: It's unclear what part is failing... installing Chocolatey itself? Or installing one (all? any?) of the packages? Can you clarify and possibly post a snippet of the command line or error?

Comment: Firstly @AnthonyMastrean, thanks for editing the question, you've wrote it better than me ;)

Secondly, apologies for the lack of information. Chocolatey installs fine. None of the packages install successfully. As mentioned the log is not helpful at all but, see below for a snippet from the log.

2015-05-18 16:33:26,613 [ERROR] - dotnet4.5 not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 No more data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the 0.9.9 series doesn't seem to play well with proxies - follow https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/243 to learn about when and what version it is fixed in. Thanks!

You can also stick with 0.9.8.33 until the fixes are in - we even have a way for you to install the older client - https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey.org/issues/162

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reply. Simple question but how do I find out what chocolatey version I am using? I've had a look around the directory but, can't seem to find it...

Comment: `choco -v` should get you the version in both old and new clients

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick, now able to download packages. I just need to amend the script now to install that specific version, hopefully shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Just a question @ferventcoder , If I wanted to amend the above script to only install the 0.9.8.33 do you have any idea on how I would achieve that? I've looked at a lot of guides but they all just say use "http://chocolatey.org/install.ps1" which installs the latest version.

Comment: So I pointed you to the chocolatey.org issue, which shows you https://chocolatey.org/install-lastposhclient.ps1